# Oracle SQL to return column values from unique rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, analytic-functions

I have a table with individual batches which can have multiple sub-batches:

```
+--------+----------+
¦Batch   +Sub-batch ¦
¦--------¦----------¦
¦B_01    ¦SB_01     ¦
¦B_02    ¦SB_02     ¦
¦B_02    ¦SB_03     ¦
¦B_03    ¦SB_04     ¦
+--------+----------+
```

Where B_ and SB_ are only names (identifiers) of batches, requiring no aggregation.

I would like to return:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
¦Batch   +Sub_Batch1 ¦Sub_Batch2 ¦
¦--------¦-----------¦-----------¦
¦B_01    ¦SB_01      ¦           ¦
¦B_02    ¦SB_02      ¦SB_03      ¦
¦B_03    ¦SB_04      ¦           ¦
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

It looks like PARTITION BY or PIVOT is the way to go but I can only seem to find aggregate functions.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Will it only have sub_batch1 and sub_batch2? Do you want to make it dynamically?

Comment: It should only ever have two sub batches but there are other similar systems where more might be possible, therefore dynamic would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only 2 sub_batches then you can simply use `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions as following:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(Batch, Sub_batch) AS
  2  (SELECT 'B_01', 'SB_01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'B_02', 'SB_02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'B_02', 'SB_03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'B_03', 'SB_04' FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT
  7      BATCH,
  8      MIN(SUB_BATCH) AS SUB_BATCH1,
  9      CASE
 10          WHEN MIN(SUB_BATCH) <> MAX(SUB_BATCH) THEN MAX(SUB_BATCH)
 11      END AS SUB_BATCH2
 12  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 13  GROUP BY BATCH
 14  ORDER BY BATCH;

BATCH      SUB_BATCH1 SUB_BATCH2
---------- ---------- ----------
B_01       SB_01
B_02       SB_02      SB_03
B_03       SB_04

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Will MIN and MAX work where the SUB_BATCH is only an identifier (alphanumeric), not a number?

Comment: Yes!! You can see it from the example given in the answer

Comment: Thanks @Tejash, somehow completely missed that one!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `row_number()` function firstly, and then use `conditional aggregation` :

```
with t as
(
select t0.*,
       row_number() over (partition by Batch order by Sub_batch) as rn
  from t0
)
select Batch,
       max(case when rn = 1 then Sub_batch end) as Sub_Batch1, 
       max(case when rn = 2 then Sub_batch end) as Sub_Batch2
  from t
 group by Batch
 order by Batch;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3a86dd8a61c4f2a4fff77abba7d0826)</kbd>